# Suggestions for making Magento CE faster

Tags: ce-1.9.0.1, slowbackend

I have a Magento CE 1.9.1.0 which is used to run a website containing 130,000 sku's . Our issue is the website seems to load slow. We have it hosted on an Amazon AWS cloud with plenty of RAM and processor speed. Yet still it is slow. 
We also setup Redis to cache the database in hopes it would speed up the site. However it still seems to load category pages slow.

We are wondering if anyone else has fasted this and what solutions they tried?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to increase performance for 50k products in 27k categories?](http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/42329/how-to-increase-performance-for-50k-products-in-27k-categories)

Comment: The more products you have, the heavier the EAV tables, so the slower it gets. Try caching HTML blocks with Varnish, it could help.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Magento is exceptionally fast as standard, it will load pages in 0.5s with all caches off and 0.2s with all caches on.

So you don't need strictly to make make Magento faster, you need to remove/change whatever is making it slow.

There's 2 bottlenecks for performance.

- Poor hosting
- Poor code

Addressing those is superbly simple,

- Use a hosting provider that specialises in high performance Magento hosting that can provide store-level support to help you scale and guide you on performance improvement
- Profile your code, and remove/re-factor poorly performing code

You'll know if your hosting provider is your bottleneck simply by installing a demo store with sample data. If it takes more than 0.5s to load with all the caches off, then there's your issue.

---

#### Whatever you do

Do not add a cache. Don't add Varnish, don't add a FPC - just fix the underlying performance issues.